# How to show all my products in Woocommerece home page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Using `storefront`, on the home page I have the categories strip with 3 images for 3 categories.

Then I can choose to show **"New In"** /  **"We recommand"** / **"Best Sellers"** etc.

I would like to show here instead of these , **ALL** my products , with endless scrolling.

So I have categories, then all of my products. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the admin setting 'WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display > Shop page display' to 'Show products'. The shop page will now show only products.

The storefront theme by default shows only 12 products per page you can override this by installing a 'storefront_products_per_page' filter.

```
add_filter( 'storefront_products_per_page', function() {
    return 1000;
});
```

Comment: I already have this, thanks, but he keeps showing me 4 rows, each row has 4 items, and they are "new in", "we recommand", "best seller". I can change which of these appears using the home page control in customize, but he always show them with 4 images (your code is inside functions.php)

Comment: As a last resort since the shop page is just a WordPress archive driven by a WP_Query you can modify the WP_Query. WooCommerce provides the action 'woocommerce_product_query' for this purpose.